# SQL Server: converting from text to varchar and then writing into text file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, varchar

I'm having problem with converting the `Text` data type into `varchar`. I need to convert that because then it's written into the text file. The problem is that only first 362 characters of `Text` converts into `varchar`:

This works

```
DECLARE @txt varchar(362) = (SELECT Text FROM Whatever WHERE id = 1)
```

Not working

```
DECLARE @txt varchar(1000) = (SELECT Text FROM Whatever WHERE id = 1)
```

The whole procedure fails on this statement, the `@txt` won't write into text file (using `xp_cmdshell`)

`varchar(MAX)` doesn't work

Thx for help

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: What version of sql server? Did you try varchar(max)?

Comment: No errors, the textfile just wont fill up, i also used varchar(MAX), not working

Comment: try to use varchar(max)

Comment: Version is sql server 2008, i used varchar(max) but then xp_cmdshell won't write that, if i just Select(cast...)  everything is fine on the result console

Comment: It won't save the query result into variable

Comment: So in fact, it's nothing to do with xp_cmdshell, and just DECLARE @txt varchar(1000) = (SELECT Text FROM Whatever WHERE id = 1); SELECT @txt; doesn't work? Is that right?

Comment: @Meff exactly that's the problem

Comment: Have you tried CONVERT: SELECT convert(varchar(length),textcolumn)?

Comment: Is that the entirety of the code logic being called by `xp_cmdshell`? Can you provide the error message it is returning?